# upload_max_filesize: php.ini or apache virtual host entry

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, fedora-22

I need a little perspective here as I am a bit confused. I was under the impression that adding a

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
  php_value post_max_size 800M
</IfModule>
```

in my vhost file for a domain would increase the `upload_max_filesize` for that domain; only it isn't. I don't want this change across the server only for one domain. So I am fine with the `phpinfo()` showing me a 2M upload file size.

Do I have to make the change in the `php.ini` as well, and if so why?

I am using Fedora 22. I have also double checked if mod_php5 is being loaded or not- it is.

Cheers!

Comment: Is your `IfModule` block inside a `VirtualHost` block?

Comment: @mattdm Yes, its because I only want this for this particular domain.

Comment: Please share your entire VirtualHost since it's unclear whenever you are using PHP FPM or mod_php